# Blade view for rich text field on description tag

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, richtext

I'm using voyager in a laravel 7 shopping app for the description of all products.

**I want to output the field for the description of the product**

`@section('description', {!! $item->description !!} )`

and

for the facebook share = `og:description" content="{!! $item->description !!}">`

When I use `{!! $item->description !!}` in the body, no problem. But in the tag the output always read the p tag and all style form the description.

The weird thing is it's working find on localhost but not on the server. I tried various combination of solution with the same result. I feel there's a quick or maybe it's just not possible?

Answer (score 0):

try `html_entity_decode()` ref link https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

`{!! $item->description !!}`

to

```php
{!! html_entity_decode($item->description) !!} // it will render html
```

Comment: no it's not working on this @section('description', {!! htmlspecialchars_decode($item->description) !!}), might something on the php admin or voyager a thing im really confuse

Answer (score 0):

If you are using laravel 7/8 you can create a blade component then you can simple call

```
<x-editor :content="$description></x-editor>
```

check out this [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#components)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 {{strip_tags(trim($item->description)}}
```